# Can't figure out why this isn't working?

Tags: php

```
<?php

$tireqty = $_POST['tireqty'];
$oilqty = $_POST['oilqty'];
$sparkqty = $_POST['sparkqty'];

$totalamount = 0.00;
define('TIREPRICE', 100);
define('OILPRICE', 10);
define('SPARKPRICE', 4);

$totalqty = 0;
$totalqty = $tireqty + $oilqty + $sparkqty;

i    f ($totalqty == 0) {
    echo "You did not enter anything in the boxes on the previous page.";
}
else {
    echo "<p>Order processed at ".date('H:i, jS F Y')."</p><br /><br />";
    echo '<p>Your order is as follows:</p>';
    echo $tireqty.' tires<br />';
    echo $oilqty.' bottles of oil<br />';
    echo $sparkqty.' spark plugs<br />';
    echo "Items ordered: ".$totalqty."<br />";

    if ($tireqty < 10) {
        $discount = 0;
    }
    elseif ($tireqty >= 10) && ($tireqty <= 49) {
        $discount = 0.05;
    }
    elseif ($tireqty >= 50) && ($tireqty <= 99) {
        $discount = 0.10;
    }
    elseif ($tireqty >= 100) {
        $discount = 0.15;
    }

    $totalamount = ($tireqty * TIREPRICE + $oilqty * OILPRICE + $sparkqty * SPARKPRICE) * (1+$discount);

    echo "Subtotal (Discount applied here): $".number_format($totalamount, 2)."<br />";

    $taxrate = 0.10;
    $totalamount = $totalamount * (1+ $taxrate);
    echo "Total including Tax: $".number_format($totalamount,2)."<br />";
}
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: post the error your are getting

Comment: Not working and it's our job to find out both what and why. Interesting attitude.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Question is incomplete

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting: "Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost/processorder.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly." in Chrome. I'm very new to PHP so I'm not sure how to setup up error reporting...

Comment: I see one thing right off the bat: a bunch of spaces within the first if: i    f ($totalqty == 0) {

Comment: Alse elseif should be else if with the space. <-- never mind I'm retarded both work in php.

Comment: Doesn't matter according to this book on PHP I'm reading.

Comment: @jli , elseif is acceptable by php without space . Javascript is the one that doesn't like elseifs (;

Comment: Guess no one saw my edit right after I posted it :P

Comment: Also, if you can't figure out how to edit your configuration file, here's how to turn on error reporting through code: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Should errors be reported in place of the "Server error The website..." everytime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am a beginner so I might wrong but here elseif ($tireqty >= 10) && ($tireqty <= 49) I would use and extra bracket:

```
elseif (($tireqty >= 10) && ($tireqty <= 49)) {
...
}
```

Hope this is it:)

Comment: Nice work @Andras! You may very well earn a badge for this question :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I am happy to learn more:) and more?:)))

Answer (score 2):

This is a terrible question but here goes... without knowing what's "not working" I can only guess:

```
i    f ($totalqty == 0) {
```

That's a syntax error. You probably meant:

```
if ($totalqty == 0) {
```

Likewise, here:

```
if ($tireqty < 10) {
        $discount = 0;
    }
    elseif ($tireqty >= 10) && ($tireqty <= 49) {
        $discount = 0.05;
    }
    elseif ($tireqty >= 50) && ($tireqty <= 99) {
        $discount = 0.10;
    }
    elseif ($tireqty >= 100) {
        $discount = 0.15;
    }
```

The entire conditions need to be enclosed in parens:

```
elseif (($tireqty >= 10) && ($tireqty <= 49)) {
    $discount = 0.05;
}
elseif (($tireqty >= 50) && ($tireqty <= 99)) {
    $discount = 0.10;
}
elseif ($tireqty >= 100) {
    $discount = 0.15;
}
```

It's possible there's a *lot more* things wrong here. Please edit your question and describe *specifically* what is not working, and what you've done to fix it, and what you need help with.

Comment: That spacing thing happened when I pasted the code in here.

Comment: @Dan: That's a good reason to describe exactly what the problem is. If you don't, we have no idea of knowing what you're asking!

Comment: Okay, this place makes you feel really crappy if you don't ask the questions right, huh? It's just that I didn't know what was wrong and I still haven't really figured out how to get error messages (error trapping?)...

Comment: @Dan: It can seem a little harsh when you first get started, but try answering a few questions and you'll understand. When someone (it's not just you!) says "This isn't working. [code]", it's kinda like dumping the entire responsibility of fixing their problem on the group. It makes answering the question very difficult. A concise, clear explanation in your question will go a *long* way toward getting better answers. Don't be discouraged by just one question!

Comment: For example, even saying *what's* not working would help. Describe the symptom if you don't know the error. If you had said "The page does not display", or "I get the error message *x*", that would help. "Not working" could be that the page shows the wrong price. Or doesn't show a price. Or works half the time. Or just doesn't do what you expect. or fails when the price is 3. Or... or... :-)